# firebase web, authenticate phone to existing account email

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

firebase web and javascript, i have an account with email and password, now I need to authenticate with the phone but to update to the previous account created with email and password, I only find that a new one is created with the phone but not to update the old one, help

Comment: See stackoverflow guidelines how and what kind of questions you can ask here. Show your efforts with some code.

Answer (score 2):

In Firebase Authentication you can't just add additional info to an existing profile. But what you *can* do is create a profile for the user with multiple providers, and then link those providers. So in your case, you'd create an additional profile with the phone number provider, and then link that to the existing email+password account.

The steps (as outlined in the documentation on ):

1. Follow the flow for [sending a verification code to the user's phone number](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#send-a-verification-code-to-the-users-phone)
2. [Get the `AuthCredential` for the user's phone auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth#get-the-intermediate-authcredential-object)
3. Now [link the auth providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking) to create a combined account.

Comment: excellent, thanks for your help friend, I solved it right now